# LiveData in Nested RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-livedata

The fragment I am coding right now is supposed to give the user a calendaric overview of his meal planning schedule. So via date picker, he can choose a time period and the program will show the user which recipes he has chosen for the chosen weekdays.
So I build a nested RecyclerView with the weekdays as parent layer and corresponding recipes as a child layer. The data class for the weekday layer looks like this :

```
data class Weekday (
    val weekday : String,
    val listWithRecipes : List<Recipe>?
        )
```

The class for the Recipe entity looks like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "Recipe")
@Parcelize
data class Recipe(
    @PrimaryKey var recipeName : String,
    var description : String?,
    var serving : Int,
    var preparationTime : Int?
) : Parcelable
```

The Adapter for the top Recycler View like this :

```
class MealPlanAdapter(private var mealplan: List<Weekday>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MealPlanAdapter.MealPlanViewHolder>(), RecipeAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MealPlanViewHolder {
        return MealPlanViewHolder(
            DailyMealplanItemBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = mealplan.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MealPlanViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val weekday = mealplan[position]
        val recipeAdapter = RecipeAdapter(this)
        recipeAdapter.submitList(weekday?.listWithRecipes)
        holder.dayOfWeek.text = weekday.weekday
        val recipeLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(holder.recyclerView.context,RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        recipeLayoutManager.initialPrefetchItemCount = 4
        holder.recyclerView.apply{
            layoutManager = recipeLayoutManager
            adapter = recipeAdapter
        }

    }

    fun setSchedule(mealplan : List <Weekday>){
        this.mealplan = mealplan
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class MealPlanViewHolder(val binding: DailyMealplanItemBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = binding.rvRecyclerView
        val dayOfWeek: TextView = binding.tvDayOfWeek
    }

    override fun onItemClick(recipe: Recipe) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

Whenever the user changes the time period, the setScheduled() method in the adapter gets called in the fragment.

```
 materialDatePickerStartDate.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(
            MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener<Any?> { selection ->
                _binding.viewmodel!!.startDateInUTCFormat = selection as Long
                _binding.tvStartDate.setText(materialDatePickerStartDate.headerText)
                adapter.setSchedule(
                    _binding.viewmodel!!.returnListWithWeekDaysAndCorrespondingRecipes(
                        _binding.viewmodel!!.startDateInUTCFormat,
                        _binding.viewmodel!!.endDateInUTCFormat
                    )


                )
            }

        )
```

The viewmodel looks like this :

```
@HiltViewModel
class MealplanViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val mealPlanRepository: MealPlanRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private lateinit var _binding: FragmentMealPlanBinding
    var startDateInUTCFormat: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
    var endDateInUTCFormat: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()    

    fun returnListWithWeekDaysAndCorrespondingRecipes(
        startDate: Long,
        endDate: Long
    ): ArrayList<Weekday> {
        var startDate = Date(startDateInUTCFormat)
        var endDate = Date(endDateInUTCFormat)
        var startDateCalendar = dateToCalendar(startDate)
        var endDateCalendar = dateToCalendar(endDate)
        val calendarDays = createListWithCalendarDates(startDateCalendar, endDateCalendar)


        return createListWithWeekDaysAndCorrespondingRecipes(calendarDays)

    }

    fun dateToCalendar(date: Date): Calendar {
        var calInstance = Calendar.getInstance()
        calInstance.setTime(date)
        return calInstance
    }

    fun createListWithCalendarDates(
        startDateCalendar: Calendar,
        endDateCalendar: Calendar
    ): ArrayList<Calendar> {
        var listWithCalendarDates = arrayListOf<Calendar>()
        while (startDateCalendar <= endDateCalendar) {
            listWithCalendarDates.add(startDateCalendar.clone() as Calendar)
            startDateCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
        }
        return listWithCalendarDates
    }

    fun createListWithWeekDaysAndCorrespondingRecipes(calendarDays: ArrayList<Calendar>): ArrayList<Weekday> {
        var dayOfWeekAsString: String
        var listWithDaysOfWeeksAndRecipes = arrayListOf<Weekday>()
        var flattenedListWithRecipes: List<Recipe>?
        for (i in 0 until calendarDays.size) {
            var dayOfWeekAsInt = calendarDays[i].get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
            dayOfWeekAsString = when (dayOfWeekAsInt) {
                1 -> "Sunday"
                2 -> "Monday"
                3 -> "Tuesday"
                4 -> "Wednesday"
                5 -> "Thursday"
                6 -> "Friday"
                else -> "Saturday"
            } 
          

            var calendarDateInString =
                transformCalendarDateIntoRequiredStringFormat(calendarDays[i])
            var listWithDateAndCorrespondingRecipes: List<MealplanScheduleWithRecipes> =
                listOf() 


            var liveDatalistWithDateAndCorrespondingRecipes =
                mealPlanRepository.getMealplanScheduleWithRecipes(calendarDateInString)


            liveDatalistWithDateAndCorrespondingRecipes.observeForever() { list ->
                listWithDateAndCorrespondingRecipes = list



                var listWithRecipes = listWithDateAndCorrespondingRecipes?.map { it.recipes }
                flattenedListWithRecipes = listWithRecipes?.flatten()
                var wochentag = dayOfWeekAsString
                listWithDaysOfWeeksAndRecipes.add(Weekday(dayOfWeekAsString, flattenedListWithRecipes))

            }    


        }


        return listWithDaysOfWeeksAndRecipes
    }

    fun transformCalendarDateIntoRequiredStringFormat(calendarDate: Calendar): String {
        var year = calendarDate.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        var month = transformCalendarMonthFormatToCorrectMonth(calendarDate)
        var day = calendarDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        return "$day" + "$month" + "$year"
    }

    fun transformCalendarMonthFormatToCorrectMonth(calendarDate: Calendar): String {
        var monthCalendarFormat = calendarDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        var monthCorrectFormat = when (monthCalendarFormat) {
            0 -> "1"
            1 -> "2"
            2 -> "3"
            3 -> "4"
            4 -> "5"
            5 -> "6"
            6 -> "7"
            7 -> "8"
            8 -> "9"
            9 -> "10"
            10 -> "11"
            else -> "12"
        }
        return monthCorrectFormat
    }

    fun datesAreReasonable(startDate: Long, endDate: Long): Boolean {
        return (startDate <= endDate)
    }


}
```

My problem is the list that is passed to the RecyclerView Adapter consists of Weekday objects, which consist of the name of the weekday and the corresponding recipes (see data class "weekday" on top).
In the method "createListWithWeekDaysAndCorrespondingRecipes" in the viewmodel I create this list in a for loop that gets all weekdays between given Dates and their corresponding recipes. However, the recipes are LiveData fetched asynchronously via Room database query while the names of the weekdays are derived synchronously in the main thread. At the end however when I create the Weekday object
(see listWithDaysOfWeeksAndRecipes.add(Weekday(dayOfWeekAsString, flattenedListWithRecipes) at the end of the for loop) I need them together at the same time. I haven't found a way how I can coordinate this successfully. At the moment the logics for adding the object to the list is in the asynchronous "observeForever" block.
See here:

```
liveDatalistWithDateAndCorrespondingRecipes.observeForever() { list ->
                listWithDateAndCorrespondingRecipes = list



                var listWithRecipes = listWithDateAndCorrespondingRecipes?.map { it.recipes }
                flattenedListWithRecipes = listWithRecipes?.flatten()
                var wochentag = dayOfWeekAsString
                listWithDaysOfWeeksAndRecipes.add(Weekday(dayOfWeekAsString, flattenedListWithRecipes))

            }
```

This creates wrong results, probably because the coordination between main thread and the observer thread doesn't work.
If I however take the logics of adding out of the observer block, the list with recipes will give me null, because of the asynchronous character of the query.

I know that I described the problem very badly. Maybe still someone got a grasp of it and can help?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid using observeForever, I expect you are using this inside a fragment or an activity which actually has a lifecyclescope that your observer can use.

Your observer should look something like this

```
liveDataList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { list ->
    // The way I do it at the moment I just set the recyclerViews adapter and layoutManager here
    // This is not the best way to do it, so please keep that in mind
    recyclerView.apply {
        adapter = MyAdapter(list)
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
    }
})
// Or if used inside an activity
liveDataList.observe(this, {})
```

This way your observer will be attached to your lifecycle and "die" together with your view. Whenever that list changes, you will show all entities in the recyclerView. HOWEVER, when you use an Array together with LiveData the LiveData object never "updates" when you just add something to that value, since the array only is a memory reference to the start of the array.

To counter this whenever you add something to your array you need to refresh the LiveData object in order to trigger an update and all observers.

```
myLiveDataObject.value.add(someOtherObject)
myLiveDataObject.value = myLiveDataObject.value
```

`myLiveDataObject.value = myLiveDataObject.value` triggers all observers that there has been a change, annoying I know

If you use it inside a viewHolder or adapter simply pass the lifecycle along with the list

I am also quite new to kotlin, keep that in mind and I guarantee you there is a better way to do this, but hope it helps